# Как решить редирект в админке?

Tags: yii2

Я использовал это расширение https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user для авторизации и регистрации через соц сети. У меня до этого в админку зашел через /admin и попадал в site/login, а щас после этого расширения попадаю в user/login который находиться в vendor.

Мне надо в site/login попасть который находиться в backend. Как это исправить? Где изменить? Никак не могу найти

Comment: В документации же все описано.

Comment: вот именно в документации не написано